# Hide tableview header when the numberOfRows in section = 0

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I'm currently trying to hid the tableview header if the section returns no rows. This is what I currently have but it return a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error at runtime:

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    let headerHeight: CGFloat

    switch section {
    case 0:
      headerHeight = 0
    case 1:
      if peopleImagesTableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 1) == 0 {
          headerHeight = 0
      } else {
        headerHeight = 40
      }
    default:
      headerHeight = 0
    }
    return headerHeight
  }
```

Comment: you need to return floating point value.

Comment: While line of code causes the error?

Comment: @rmaddy sorry for making that an answer.:d

Comment: @TusharSharma The problem is that the OP is already returning a floating point value.

Comment: @rmaddy variable is of type CGFloat but he is returning value as 40 or 0. Is that okk??

Comment: @TusharSharma Of course. The compiler happily converts those number literals into the proper type when the app is built.

Comment: @rmaddy thanks will keep that in mind.

Comment: Can you provide all functions of UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource that you implemented?

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem at this line `if peopleImagesTableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 1) == 0 {`. Because `tableView(_:heightForHeaderInSection:)` runs before `tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)` so it can't know the number of rows and the app crashes. You should check your data array instead of calling `numberOfRows` function. For example:

```
if data[1].count == 0 {
    headerHeight = 0
} else {
    headerHeight = 40
}
```